# Program won't allow 2 inputs?

Tags: c++, input

So I am trying to get the user to input their name and height.

I have got other code.

I have got this.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
int name1; 
cout << "What's your name?"; 
cin >> name1; 

int height1; 
cout << "What's your height?"; 
cin >> height1; 

return 0; 
}
```

The issue is that it won't allow the user to enter their height. Any ideas?

Comment: You have `name1` as an `int`. That is wrong. Also, `cin >>` input is whitespace delimited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem is, that you're using int variables instead of std::string. However, you already included the `<string>` header file, so you probably want to do this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
std::string name1; 
cout << "What's your name?"; 
cin >> name1; 

std::string height1; 
cout << "What's your height?"; 
cin >> height1; 

return 0; 
}
```

Otherwise it only works if you enter integer numbers - but that doesn't make much sense for an 'name' input.

**Edit:** If it's also your requirement to input names with whitespaces, you could use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
std::string name1; 
cout << "What's your name?"; 
getline(cin, name1);

std::string height1; 
cout << "What's your height?"; 
getline(cin, height1);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So what happens if I type `"Bob T. Fish"`? (i.e. it's kinda broken)

Comment: Multiple words won't work, he will want getline for that. But as a quick intro to C++ streams this isn't bad.

Comment: Also please mention the use of `std::getline`

Comment: Thanks, I added also a solution with std::getline!

Comment: @TyKohler Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't leave a comment just to say “thank you”. If this answer solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted - thank you.